# How do you ask Visual Studio to be pointed to the source code of a blazor component in github

Tags: github, blazor, components

In order to see the source code of a Blazor component in GitHub, I right clicked on the component name and picked Go to definition while using Visual Studio, but nothing happened. I believe that I have clicked on the same option before and was pointed to the source code in github. Am I mistaken?